# Calculating numeric differences per group in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series, dataframe

My Dataframe has the following structure:

```
patient_id  |  timestamp  |  measurement
A           |  2014-10-10 |  5.7
A           |  2014-10-11 |  6.3
B           |  2014-10-11 |  6.1
B           |  2014-10-10 |  4.1
```

I would like to calculate a `delta` (difference) between each measurement of each patient.

The result should look like:

```
patient_id  |  timestamp  |  measurement  |    delta
A           |  2014-10-10 |  5.7          |     NaN
A           |  2014-10-11 |  6.3          |     0.6
B           |  2014-10-11 |  6.1          |     2.0
B           |  2014-10-10 |  4.1          |     NaN
```

How can this be done most-elegantly in pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the 'measurement' column and pass the method [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff), transform returns a series with an index aligned to the original df:

```
In [4]:

df['delta'] = df.groupby('patient_id')['measurement'].transform(pd.Series.diff)
df
Out[4]:
  patient_id   timestamp  measurement  delta
0          A  2014-10-10          5.7    NaN
1          A  2014-10-11          6.3    0.6
2          B  2014-10-10          4.1    NaN
3          B  2014-10-11          6.1    2.0
```

**EDIT**

If you are intending to apply some sorting on the result of `transform` then sort the df first:

```
In [10]:

df['delta'] = df.sort(columns=['patient_id', 'timestamp']).groupby('patient_id')['measurement'].transform(pd.Series.diff)
df
Out[10]:
  patient_id   timestamp  measurement  delta
0          A  2014-10-10          5.7    NaN
1          A  2014-10-11          6.3    0.6
2          B  2014-10-11          6.1    2.0
3          B  2014-10-10          4.1    NaN
```

Comment: I failed to understand how does the difference take the `timestamp` into consideration

Comment: Sorry you asked for a delta on `measurement` not on `timestamp`, as such the `timestamp` is not affected, can you explain better as this is not mentioned at all in your question nor is it apparent in your desired output

Comment: I do not want to rely on the order of rows, but on the order of the time-stamps. I edited the original question to clarify

Comment: Do the same thing just sort on timestamp first. `df.sort("timestamp", inplace=True)`