# pandas, calculate diffrential, efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Consider a dataframe of a measurement, for each patient and a timestamp

```
patient     |  timestamp  |  x
A           |  2014-10-10 |  5.7
A           |  2014-10-11 |  6.3
B           |  2014-10-11 |  6.1
B           |  2014-10-10 |  4.1
```

My goal is do calculate `d`, the difference between `x` in a row, and `x` in the closest previous measurement.

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178740/calculating-numeric-differences-per-group-in-pandas), this is the code I used

```
df.sort("timestamp", inplace=True)
df['d'] = df.groupby('patient')['x'].transform(pd.Series.diff).fillna(0)
```

However,  when trying to run this code on a dataframe with many measurements

```
patient     |  timestamp  |  x_1  |  ...  |  x_n
```

Using a simple loop:

```
df.sort("timestamp", inplace=True)
g=df.groupby('patient')
for x in df.columns:
    if x.find('x')>=0:
       df[x.replace('x','d')] = g[x].transform(pd.Series.diff).fillna(0)
```

**The code runs very very slooow,**

Is there a more efficient way to calculate the difference vector and concatenating it to the vector of measurements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` can be an expensive operation, and you're preforming the same one multiple times in your loop. Try to do all your calculations with fewer `groupby`s, if possible:

```
cols = [col in df where col[0] = 'x']
res = df.groupby('patient')[cols].diff().fillna(0)
```

To concatenate, first rename and then join:

```
res = res.rename(columns=(lambda col: 'd'+col[1:]))
df = df.join(res, how='outer')
```

As a rule of thumb with pandas and numpy, if you're using a loop, you're probably doing something wrong. Or at least in a sub-optimal way.

Comment: Thanks @ari, I do need to concatenate the result to new columns (e.g. starting with `d`)